# Paperclip::Tasks Error on Heroku running Delayed Paperclip and Delayed Job

Tags: heroku, paperclip, delayed-job, delayed-paperclip

When Heroku starts up, I receive the error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/delayed_paperclip-2.9.0/lib/delayed_paperclip.rb:81:in `paperclip_definitions': uninitialized constant Paperclip::Tasks (NameError)
```

When running Paperclip and delayed_paperclip with Delayed Job.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure :has_attached_file precedes :process_in_background in the model. I had them in the wrong order.